# Bergman spaces and Dirichlet spaces equvalency

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\alpha > -1$ and $p>0$. $A_{\alpha}^{p}$ is Bergman space and $D_{\alpha}^{p}$ is Dirchlet space. I want to know exact proof of why
$$D_{\alpha}^{p}= A_{\alpha-p}^{p}$$ for $\alpha> p-1$?

Comment: you are supposed to define both side

Comment: I define both side but I cannot achieve same equality in both side :(

Comment: define both side here in your question

Comment: Is it possible that you send me this question answer?

Comment: plz someone help me......

Comment: You are not capable to define your spaces so you have no reason to ask the question